# Creating a website in html not xml

Tags: html

Call me crazy but I have been trying to make an HTML website using Visual Studio 2012 but every time I open the program and create a webpage it automatically makes it an XML. Is this normal? Is this the normal start to an HTML webpage or do I need to do something to change it?

I have looked through the Microsoft webpages help and the Visual Studio help and I cannot find anything that explains this to me.

All I want to do is make an HTML website

```
<head>

<style>

</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1></h1>
<h2></h2>

</body>
</html>
```

I know I can do this using a notepad.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What do you mean "makes it an XML"?

Comment: @BoltClock I have Visual Studio 2012. I want to make a website using Visual Studio. When I open the make a blank website and I open the config file it is an XML. I do not want an XML website, I want an HTML website. I looked at the link and I am not finding where you can change this in Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

That is not XML brother. That is what HTML is like. Anywhere you go, you'll find the same pattern, and so does Visual Studio follows.

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>  
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1></h1>
  <h2></h2>
  <p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

That is HTML, you don't need to do anything just add the content for the heading or paragraph elements. XML is something else, if you're confused you should first atleast try to check what's the difference here. :)

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, I know this is html, what I get is:  <?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>

    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>

</configuration>

Comment: Whoops! You're getting an error. :) That's not the webpage that is being display, you can see that it is an error message by the IIS (server you've installed on your computer) Go to the link and learn how to change the settings in your web.config file to run the website...Good luck ... :)